# scrolling is choppy in chrome when background image is fixed

Tags: google-chrome, background, scroll, fixed

I'm trying to create a parallax website. But then I have an issue with fixed positioning.

I have several sections , each with a `background-attachment:fixed`.
A `position:fixed` menu bar on the top with an hidden element in it on top of all sections.
A google map 100% with in one of the sections.

Now, the problem is when I scroll the page with animation in google chrome, the scrolling does not go smooth and it flashes several times while scrolling.

I do the scrolling with greensock scrollTo plugin , but that is not the problem as I also tested it with jquery `.animate()` method. Same result.

I did a research , and found out that chrome has a bug or problem with Fixed positioning ( and sometimes when you put hidden element in it )
Some pages suggested to use these two with the fixed elements :

```
-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden; 
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
```

I added this to the fixed menu and some of the choppy behavior of it reduced , but still not smooth.
If I add this to the sections with `background-attachment:fixed` elements, the scrolling animation goes smooth but does not act as fixed anymore.

Somebodies says that chrome has problem with large images, some says it has issue with fixed position and somebodies had a solution that did not work for me :D

I uploaded the page :
http://www.FarzanMohajerani.com/test/parallax
just click anywhere on the page to scroll.

I also created a jsFiddle with the exact same code. But I don't know why it doesn't have the problem in jsFiddle :
    http://jsfiddle.net/Farzanmc/cRqxT/5/

It would be great if anyone could direct me to the right solution or remind me if I'm doing anything wrong.
Thanks

Comment: I also uploaded the zip file of the page if anyone interested to download and take a look : http://www.FarzanMohajerani.com/test/parallax/Parallax.zip

I tried the tutorial on stellar.js in the tutsplus : http://webdesigntutsplus.s3.amazonaws.com/tuts/338_parallax/src/index.html

Even there, in the last slide where the background image is fixed , the scrolling animation goes choppy in the last seconds.

Answer (score 3):

This solved the issue for me:

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```

Adding this rule turns the element into a layer in Chrome, which avoids repainting. In my unique situation the error was caused by browser re-painting.

Comment: I had a flexslider that would cause choppy scrolling, this fixed it for me

Answer (score 1):

I', having the same problem with Chrome at the moment and I narrowed down the cause to the following combination:

1) background: fixed;
2) transform: (any transform, even just putting scale(1), would instantly break it).

As long as an element that contains fixed background image doesn't have any "transform" on it, it works fine. But as soon as you even add "transform: scale(1);" which doesn't actually make any real transformation, it completely breaks the fixed background image. You can start scrolling, but it disappears. If it was outside of the screen, it will never appear at all, no matter how far you scroll.

So essentially, the problem is that Chrome at the moment can't handle fixed background images in transformed elements. No matter which level of descendent or ancestor we are talking about.
The thing is, this is pretty much an essential stuff that and I'm really hoping that it gets fixed as soon as possible, because it's extremely limiting. You can't disregard Chrome as if it's IE6.

And you can't apply "position: fixed;" on an "img" element, because it will be fixed to the first "transformed" ancestor, not to the real screen, since that's apparently how it's supposed to be treated, according to W3C. Although, some new value would be welcomed, some that can break all the way to the very window, and fixit to those coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

I ran i to a same problem and fixed it this way:
I had to deal with fixed header on a website and anytime i would scroll with a mouse wheel the header would get choppy.... I had a display:none element in a header and as soon as i removed the element, header became fixed and steady, now it displays well no matter how fast i scroll.